# Linq with join - Get single result

Tags: linq

I'm stucked with a linq query and I need a little bit of help.

I have the following tables

Table: Client

```
ClientId     Name           Age
(integer)
--------    ----------    -----
  12635      John          23
  87263      Derek         43
  65237      Sarah         36
  84735      Alice         28
```

Table: Action

```
Id          Action      ObjecId 
                        (varchar)
--------    ---------   ---------
  202        Firefox       87263
  203        Chrome        65237
  204        Android       87263
  205        Explorer      84735 
  206        Firefox       12635
```

My goal is to join both tables using `ClientId` and `ObjectId` fields. And for the Action table for each user I need to get only one record. If user has two records I need to get only the one with value='Android'

So the result with the above data should be:

```
Derek      Android 
Sarah      Chrome
Alicie     Explorer
John       Firefox
```

I'm using the following approach.

```
var query = Set as IQueryable<Client>;

var actionQuery = Set as IQueryable<Action>

query= query.Join(actionQuery, 
                  Client=> Client.ClientId.ToString(),
                  Action => Action.ObjectId.ToString(),
                  (Client, Action) => Client);
```

With the above I have a duplicate record for Derek, I need to get only one record for him, but I don't know how to do it. If a user has 2 records I need to get only the one with value='Android'.

Please, can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Silly question - what if there are two records for a particular client but none of them is 'Android'? And seriously - why don't you group the results by ClientId and within each group select the record with highest Action Id? I believe it's what you're looking for.

Comment: what if there are two records for a particular client but none of them is 'Android'? -> this scenario is not possible. In case a client have two records one of them always is Android. Your query is not valid due I can't order by actionId, this query won't get me the result I want if Android action record would have a lower id

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a record where the ActionId is the highest, I'd do the following:

```
query = query.Join(actionQuery, 
                   Client=> Client.ClientId.ToString(),
                   Action => Action.ObjectId.ToString(),
                   (Client, Action) => new { Client = Client, Action = Action })
             .GroupBy(g => g.Client.Id)
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Action.Id).First());
```

EDIT:
After the OP specified that if there are more actions for a particular client, one of those is **always** "Android" and this one must be chosen, I'm providing the following query:

```
query = query.Join(actions,
                   Client => Client.Id.ToString(),
                   Action => Action.ObjectId.ToString(),
                   (Client, Action) => new { Client = Client, Action = Action })
             .GroupBy(g => g.Client.Id)
             .Select(g => (g.Count() > 1) ? g.Where(gr => "Android".Equals(gr.Action.ActionDesc)).First() : g.First());
```